# Disable log4net errors on command prompt while using rotractor/Selenium web driver/Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, log4net

Is there a way to completely disable log4net errors appearing on npm console while running test cases . I am using Protractor and  Selenium Web driver. I would like to know if this is possible through Protractor's config file Capabilities.

Comment: provide some code ... like log4net configratuon .. etc